# Iterating an array from grep

Tags: shell, ubuntu-12.04

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server here and I have a process that can use some ports in my system.

The way I have to track these ports is this command:

`ps ax | grep thin | grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\:[0-9]{1,5}'`

Now I want to use this command as an array variable in a shell script.

How do I parse the values there to an array?

The value looks like this:

`0.0.0.0:3000 0.0.0.0:3001 0.0.0.0:3002 0.0.0.0:3003`

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/split-string-based-on-delimiter-in-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put the output of your command into an array:

```
array=( $(ps ax | grep thin | grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\:[0-9]{1,5}') )
```

Comment: Wow.. that was simple! Thanks a lot! =D